# ValueError: Invalid parameter C for estimator SelectFromModel when using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, logistic-regression, grid-search

I'm using `python 3.7.6`, and I'm trying to tune some hyperparameters using `GridSearchCV`

I created a `pipeline` with the following steps: `scaling-> feature selection -> model`

But I'm getting error about the `C` parameter of the feature selection step.

```
    steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
             ('FeatureSelection', SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear'))),
             ('SVM', SVC())]
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)  # define the pipeline object.

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=30, stratify=y)

    parameteres = {'SVM__C': [0.001, 0.1, 10, 100, 10e5],
                   'SVM__gamma':[0.1,0.01],
                   'FeatureSelection__C':['0','0.5']}
    grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameteres, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("pipeline score: ", grid.score(X_test, y_test))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter C for estimator SelectFromModel(estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None,
                                             dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                                             intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None,
                                             max_iter=100, multi_class='auto',
                                             n_jobs=None, penalty='l1',
                                             random_state=None,
                                             solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
                                             verbose=0, warm_start=False),
                max_features=None, norm_order=1, prefit=False, threshold=None). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, the pipeline looks for a parameter `C` in `SelectFromModel`, can't find one (unsurprisingly, since the module does not have such a parameter), and raises an error. Since you actually want the parameter `C` of `LogisticRegression`, you should go a level deeper: change `FeatureSelection__C` to `FeatureSelection__estimator__C` in your `parameters` grid and you will be fine.

Comment: @user3668129 You sure?? I've actually tried it (different data) and it worked (I even replicated the error). You sure have the correct 2 underscores (`__`)?

Comment: you gave me good hint. I had to remove the "" and it works:
'FeatureSelection__estimator__C': [0.1, 0.5]

Comment: @user3668129 I told ya ;) (but you already show single quotes, not double ones)